# compiler doesn't recognize FILE* variable

Tags: c

(using Visual Studio 2012 C++ compiler)

The following compiles just fine:

```
FILE *filePointer = fopen("file.txt","wb");
```

But if I try to break it into two lines:

```
FILE *filePointer;
filePointer = fopen("file.txt","wb");
```

On the second line, the compiler doesn't recognize `filePointer` as a variable.  I get errors like

```
Error:  this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
```

or

```
error C2040: 'filePointer' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'FILE *'
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'FILE *' to 'int'
```

Why doesn't it remember that `filePointer` is a `FILE*`?

Comment: Which #includes do you use?

Comment: (using Visual Studio 2012 C++ compiler)

Comment: c++ now has diverged from c. they are no longer compatible. in some particular compiler, there may be some issues. and actually vs no longer supports c specifically since the name change.

Comment: have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z.aspx. hope you can change your tool if you really want to do some serious c.

Comment: Can you present a complete file that exhibits that problem?  For example, does slapping a `main()` function around just the code you presented, and putting `#include <stdio.h>` in front of it yield a file about which VS complains?

Comment: Does the code maybe appear at file scope, instead of in a function?

Comment: VS2012 still implements C89 rules, local variable declarations must precede statements.  So the rough diagnostic is that you changed more than one thing, you also added a statement *before* the variable declaration.  VS2013 no longer has this restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a declaration:

```
FILE *filePointer = fopen("file.txt","wb");
```

This is also a declaration:

```
FILE *filePointer;
```

This, however, is a statement.

```
filePointer = fopen("file.txt","wb");
```

Declarations declare variables, and can appear at the top level (declaring a global variable), or within a function (declaring a local variable).  Statements, on the other hand, can only appear in functions, and can access local or global variables.  Only declarations can appear outside of functions, so if you put a statement there, the compiler will try to treat it as a declaration, and generally give you a confusing error message about something being wrong with a declaration, like the ones you quote.